# Animate WPF Drag Adorner movement

Tags: wpf, animation, adorner

in our application we use a adorner for some fake drag & drop. The adorner doesn't follow to mouse but is set to some specific coordinates on the screen when the mouse moves.

```
double xPosLocation = (int)(dividerDistanceXAxis * virtualPosition) + YAxisData.SpacingLeft;
double yPosLocation = CalculateValueToYPosition(VirtualPriceOfVehicle);
DragAdorner.UpdatePosition(xPosLocation - offsetX, yPosLocation + offsetY);
```

This works fine so far. But with a code like this the adorner jumps from one location to another. This is how it was supposed to work but it would be nice to have some smooth movement transitions when the adorner it set to a new position.

Can it be done? Since I see no position property I guess it is not possible to do a double-animation or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `DependencyProperty` for animation

```
public class DragAdorner
{
    public Point Position
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(PositionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PositionProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PositionProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Position", typeof(Point), typeof(DragAdorner), new UIPropertyMetadata(PositionChanged));

    private static void PositionChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePosition(Position);
    }
}
```

Then you could do something like this (not tested)

```
double xPosLocation = (int)(dividerDistanceXAxis * virtualPosition) + YAxisData.SpacingLeft;
double yPosLocation = CalculateValueToYPosition(VirtualPriceOfVehicle);
Point newLocation = new Point(xPosLocation, yPosLocation);

PointAnimation myPointAnimation = new PointAnimation();
myPointAnimation.From = DragAdorner.Position;
myPointAnimation.To = newLocation;
myPointAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
myStoryboard.Children.Add(myPointAnimation);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(myPointAnimation, DragAdorner.Position);
myStoryboard.Begin();
```